Extract a common mean for a split cohort with metafor
I want to calculate the mean of a variable X for an entire cohort, which has been divided into several subgroups; therefore, I want to code a Fixed Effect Model, using the mean of X for each subgroup, their respective SD, and respective sample sizes.
Is there any way of doing this and obtaining the common mean(X) and the common SD(X) for the coalesced set?
Preferentially using metafor for R, or another R package.
I´ve tried using function rma(yi = yi, sei = sei, method = "FE"), with yi for the vector of mean(X), but I haven´t been able to find the existence of a function or element with the rma object referring to the pooled SD

If you want the mean and SD for the entire cohort, then see: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/384950/1934 The generalization of these equations to more than two groups should be obvious. Here is some R code to show that this allows the recovery of the mean and SD of the total group.
### simulate some data
n.total <- 100
grp <- sample(1:3, size=n.total, replace=TRUE, prob=c(.2,.3,.5))
y   <- rnorm(n.total, mean=ifelse(grp == 1, 1, 10), sd=2)

### means and SDs of the subgroups
ni  <- c(by(y, grp, length))
mi  <- c(by(y, grp, mean))
sdi <- c(by(y, grp, sd))

### want to get mean and SD of the total group
mean(y)
sd(y)

### mean = weighted mean (weights = group sizes)
m.total <- sum(ni*mi)/sum(ni)

### SD = sqrt((within-group sum-of-squares plus between-group sum-of-squares) / (n.total - 1))
sd.total <- sqrt((sum((ni-1) * sdi^2) + sum(ni*(mi - m.total)^2)) / (sum(ni) - 1))

### check that we get the right values
m.total
sd.total


Thanks. But is there an element in the rma object, or a function in the package that would yield the SD of the pooled mean?

What do you mean by "SD of the pooled mean"? If you want sd.total as in the example, them no.
